# Phylogenetic tree tip color in v.phylomaker r package

Tags: r

I am using `V.phylomaker` R package for generating the phylogenetic tree of my data. I successfully ran the code and generated the circular phylogeny plot (CSV file used and figure generated is attached). I tried to give three colours for tip labels to my figure based on the three categories (Invasive, Naturalised and Casual) that I have in my data using the following r function

```
my_colours <- c("red", "blue", "green")

libarary(V.phylomaker)

plot(tree_random, cex=.6, type = "fan", label.offset =.1, no.margin = TRUE, tip.color = my_colours[as.factor(data$stage)])
```

However, using the above function by default colours are attributed in alphabetical order to species in each category and due to this some species which should get red colour in the figure get blue or green colour and vice versa and which happens mainly to genus with two or three species. Simply, I want to colour invasive species with red, naturalised with blue and casual plant species with green colour.

Comment: What is `tree_random`? Can you share more of your code? Can you share you data in a reproducible format?

Comment: None of this makes sense. Edit your question to include the output from `dput(data)`